# como ajusto el tamaño de un boton en android studio, a la pantalla del dispositivo?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

soy nuevo en el desarrollo android y he estado iniciando con un proyecto basico, el tema es que requiero botones que se adapten al tamaño de la pantalla y no me refiero por el lugar sino que por ejemplo si en una pantalla pequeña, los botones tendran un tamaño, en una pantalla mas grande los botones **mantengan ese "aspecto"** *por ejemplo si en una pantalla pequeña el boton es de 10x10 en una pantalla del doble de tamaño este sea de 20x20*

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar estas paginas, lo que tratas de hacer se llama normalizado de pixeles:

https://medium.com/simform-engineering/create-responsive-design-in-react-native-f84522a44365

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/react-native-styles-normalization-e8ce77a3110c

En mi caso me funciono mejor el segundo link que te doy porque toma en cuenta el aspect ratio, sin embargo, ya es cuestion de que juegues con las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

La forma de manejar eso es a través de **dimensiones** en XML.
Esta página de ayuda de Android Developers te aclarará mejor el tema:
[Cómo brindar compatibilidad con diferentes tamaños de pantalla](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?hl=es-419)